# How create stored procedure with select and update

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have table `id, title, showCount`.

I need get `TOP 10` row from table and set to `showCount +1`.

How do this?

Comment: First tell us what you tried?

Comment: What does it mean "Top"?

Comment: @skk, I don't tried. I create one request sql SELECT TOP. and 10 request UPDATE showCount.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can not understand your purpose, but you can try this

```
CREATE TABLE #tbl (id int identity(1,1), title varchar(50), showCount int)

INSERT INTO #tbl (title, showCount) 
VALUES ('q',1),('qw',2),('qe',3),('qr',4),('qt',5),('qy',6),('qu',7),('qh',8),('qx',9),('qs',10), ('qs',100)


UPDATE T1
SET T1.showCount=T1.showCount+1
FROM #tbl T1
     JOIN (SELECT TOP 10 id, showCount 
           FROM #tbl) T2 ON T1.id=T2.id

SELECT *
FROM #tbl

DROP TABLE #tbl
```

Also, you need to understand that in this example `TOP 10` rows will be updated in random order.

You can find how to [CREATE PROCEDURE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx) in Books OnLine (F1).

Comment: Those `top 10` records in your query are ordered by "random", usually it's not the case :-).

Comment: @MichałPowaga I don't know how to say it in English, but in Russia we say: Which is a question such is an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE YourProceduresNameHere

AS

-- Put the code you want to run here
```

You may find [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx) interesting.